# Unjustified upper bound of Taylor expansion of exponential

Tags: calculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion, approximation-theory

It's simple to see that, for $x>0$, the exponential function is lower bounded by its truncated Taylor expansion:

$$e^x = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!} $$

If we truncate this at $k< \infty$, we are getting a lower bound, as we are just summing over positive quantities. This gives us:

$$\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{x^j}{j!} < e^x $$

However, in [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1016/0167-6377%2895%2900032-0) at page 3, after equation 2.4,  I have found the following bound. Let $\epsilon \in (0,1]$, and $a \in [-1,1]$

$$e^{\epsilon a/2} \leq 1+ \frac{\epsilon a}{2} + \frac{\epsilon^2}{6}$$

This works numerically, but I don't have any intuition for the reason it works. Let's analyze the last term, which is the most troublesome one. They obviously removed the $a$ term from the "Taylor" expansion. However it's not clear how they played with the $/2$ at the denominator. The right term I expect from Taylor would be
$$\frac{(\epsilon a /2)^2}{2!} = \frac{(\epsilon a)^2}{4*2!} = \frac{(\epsilon a)^2}{8} < \frac{(\epsilon )^2}{8} < \frac{(\epsilon)^2}{6}$$

What this bound is saying is that it bounds the remaining terms of the Taylor expansion centered in 0 of $e^{\epsilon a /2}$
$$\frac{\epsilon}{6} \geq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(\epsilon a/2)^k $$

From here I don t know how to proceed. I wish I could apply the convergence criteria of the gometric series, but there is $1/k!$ at the denominator that prevents me from doing it, and I don t have other ideas.

Numerically, I also checked if this works also removing the $/2$ at the denominator of the exponent. To my surprise, also the bound they propose don't  work anymore.

```
epsilon = 1
ra=np.linspace(-1, 1, 3000)

one, two, three, four = [], [], [], []
for a in ra:
    one.append(    np.exp(epsilon*a) <= 1 + epsilon*a + (epsilon)**2/3 )  # original 
    two.append(    np.exp(epsilon*a) <= 1 + epsilon*a + (epsilon*a)**2/3 )  # taylor but with 6
    three.append(  np.exp(epsilon*a) <= 1 + epsilon*a + (epsilon*a)**2/2 )  # taylor right
    four.append(  np.exp(epsilon*a) <= 1 + epsilon*a + (epsilon*a)**2/2 )  # taylor right


print("orig \t\t\t", np.all(one))
print("taylor but with 6 \t", np.all(two))
print("taylor right \t\t", np.all(three))
print("taylor but with 4 \t\t", np.all(four))
```

Can you help me please understand the idea behind this step? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that looking at the remainder of the first-degree Taylor polynomial is not good enough to get your inequality. Looking at the second-degree polynomial seems to be barely enough to get your bound.

The [Lagrange form of the remainder term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) $R(x)$ in $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + R(x)$ is $R(x) = \frac{1}{6} e^\xi x^3$ where $\xi$ is between $0$ and $x$.

Plugging in $x=\epsilon a / 2$ yields
$e^{\epsilon a / 2} = 1 + \frac{\epsilon a}{2} + \frac{\epsilon^2 a^2}{8} + \frac{1}{48} e^{\xi} \epsilon^3 a^3$ for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $\epsilon a/2$.

It now suffices to show
$$\frac{\epsilon^2 a^2}{8} + \frac{1}{48} e^{\xi} \epsilon^3 a^3 \le \frac{\epsilon^2}{6}.$$
Or equivalently, it suffices to show
$$\frac{a^2}{8} + \frac{1}{48} e^{\xi} \epsilon a^3 \le \frac{1}{6}.$$
This holds because $\xi \le \epsilon |a|/2 \le 1/2$ and so the left-hand side can be bounded as
$$\frac{a^2}{8} + \frac{1}{48} e^{\xi} \epsilon a^3
\le \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{48} e^{1/2}$$
which is just barely smaller than $1/6$.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to find $c$ such that if $|x| \leq 1$ then $\left | e^{x/2} - 1 - (x/2) \right | \leq cx^2$. (This whole mess with $\epsilon$ and $a$ is really just obfuscating that.)

From the Lagrange remainder, you have

$$\left | e^{x/2} - 1 - {x/2} \right | = \left | \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k!} \frac{x^k}{2^k} + \frac{1}{(n+1)!} e^{\xi/2} \frac{x^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}} \right |$$

where $\xi$ is between $0$ and $x$ and $n \geq 1$. (With $n=1$ the first term on the RHS is just $0$ since it is an empty sum.) So you can write

$$\left | e^{x/2} - 1 - {x/2} \right | \leq \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k!} \frac{|x|^k}{2^k} + \frac{1}{(n+1)!} e^{|x|/2} \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}.$$

You can try to increase $n$ until this works out as you want it to. With $n=1$ you have $\frac{1}{8} e^{|x|/2} x^2$ but $\frac{e^{1/2}}{8}>1/6$ so this is not good enough for your goal.

With $n=2$ you end up looking at $\frac{1}{8} x^2 + \frac{e^{1/2}}{48} |x|^3$, so it suffices to show $\frac{e^{1/2}}{48} \leq \frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{24}$ i.e. $e^{1/2} \leq 2$. This follows from the same kind of argument, just rearrange $e^{1/2} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{2} e^{1/2}$.

As an aside, if $x \geq 0$ is small enough that $x^{n+1} \leq (n+1)!$, then:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!} \leq e^x \leq \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}}{1-\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}.$$

One convenient sufficient condition for this is $x \leq \frac{n+1}{e}$.

Comment: Sorry, where is the $16$ coming from? With $f(x)=e^{x/2}$ we have $f''(\xi)=\frac{1}{4} e^{\xi/2}$ so the Lagrange remainder is $\frac{1}{2!} \frac{e^{\xi/2}}{4} x^2 = \frac{e^{\xi/2}}{8} x^2$. Maybe I've made a mistake.

Comment: @angryavian There is the $1/2$ from Taylor, another $1/2$ from the derivative of $e^{x/2}$, and the $1/4$ from $(x/2)^2=x^2/4$. Though I actually am missing a fifth factor of 2 since the derivative in question is the second derivative. So thanks.

Comment: If you are using the Taylor series of $e^{x/2}$ then shouldn't you be plugging in $x^2$? You would plug in $(x/2)^2$ if you are using the Taylor series of $e^x$. Either way the remainder will be $\frac{e^{\xi/2}}{8} x^2$.

Comment: @angryavian Good catch, I mixed some stuff up. That seems to create a problem for this argument, because $e^{1/2}/8>1/6$. Working on a fix.

Comment: @angryavian Fixed up. Seems to be the same conclusion you came to, that it suffices to consolidate the actual quadratic term and its remainder as error terms to get the desired result.